# Density operator in different bases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, observables

This may sound like a silly question, and it probably arises from a weak understanding of the concept.

What I was wondering is: given a density operator $\varrho=\sum_{i,j}p_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|$, can we find separate bases for which $\varrho$ is diagonal, but presenting different eigenvalues?

Mainly I was considering the example of when $\dot{\varrho}=0$. In this case $\varrho$ is diagonal in the Energy eigenbases: this grants us a nice representation of $\varrho$ as we can clearly observe its eigenvalues for each energy level. My question would then be: is possible to find a second bases(not necesseraly an observable eigenbasis) for which $\varrho$ becomes diagonal but presenting different entries?

Intuitively I would think that this should obviously possible as long as some commutation relation is respected ($=0$), but the whole idea is becoming quite confusing to me.

Comment: The eigenvalues are invariant under a change of basis, i.e. they are a property of $\rho$, not of the choice of the basis in which you represent it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is no.  The eigenvalues of an operator - which are simply the diagonal entries when that operator is diagonalized - are uniquely defined up to trivial reordering. Furthermore, the vectors belonging to distinct eigenspaces are orthogonal because $\rho$ is self-adjoint and therefore symmetric.

> so if I am given a diagonal density operator, and then someone claims that ϱ˙=0, then I know for a fact that the ϱ I was given is being represented in the energy basis, right?

No, not quite.  If two energy eigenspaces appear in the density operator with the same probability, then you might use a basis in which $\varrho$ is diagonal but $H$ is not.

For example, consider the 2-level Hamiltonian and density operator in some basis $\{|1\rangle,|2\rangle\}$. $$H=\pmatrix{E&0\\0&-E} \qquad \varrho = \pmatrix{0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.5}$$

Obviously $[\varrho,H]=0 \implies \dot\varrho = 0$.  However, if we change to a new basis
$$|1\rangle = \frac{|a\rangle+|b\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \qquad |2\rangle = \frac{|a\rangle-|b\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

then the Hamiltonian and density operator become
$$H = \pmatrix{0 & E \\ E & 0}\qquad \varrho = \pmatrix{0.5 & 0\\ 0 & 0.5}$$

As a result, even though $\dot \varrho = 0$, we have a basis $\{|a\rangle,|b\rangle\}$ which is *not* an energy eigenbasis, but in which $\varrho$ is diagonal.

This is a nice reminder that $[\varrho,H]=0$ implies that **there exists** a basis in which $\varrho$ and $H$ are simultaneously diagonalized; however, this does not imply that **every** basis which diagonalizes one also diagonalizes the other.

Comment: so if I am given a diagonal density operator, and then someone claims that $\dot{\varrho}=0$, then I know for a fact that the $\varrho$ I was given is being represented in the energy basis, right?

Comment: @OtiDioti If $\dot \rho=0$, then you know that it commutes with the Hamiltonian (von Neumann equation). Hence, there exists a basis in which the density operator and the Hamiltonian are both diagonal. Nevertheless, you can represent $\rho$ in any suitable basis. The fact that the derivative is with respect to time is zero is basis independent.

Comment: From this, can I infer that if the $\varrho$ I am given is already diagonal, then we know it to be in the energy eigenbasis?

Comment: @OtiDioti No, you cannot.  I have updated my answer with a counterexample.

Comment: I like the answers that contain a lot of math. They are the clearest. +1